# Using nth-child to cycle through items, but ignore the first item

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, is it possible to use `nth-child` to repeat every 3 items, but **ignore** the first one in the list?

For instance, I need the first item in the list to have no specific colour<sup>1</sup> then the items to cycle through red, green and blue.

```
Transparent | Red | Green | Blue | Red | Green | Blue | Red | Green | Blue
```

If the first item didn't have to be ignored, it would simply be the following...

```
li:nth-child(3n+1) { color:red; }
li:nth-child(3n+2) { color:green; }
li:nth-child(3n+3) { color:blue; }
```

But I can't figure out a CSS-only way of doing this while ignoring the first item

(<sup>1</sup> - I'm from the UK)

Comment: not a first-child - nth-child.

Comment: Oops, thanks @Andrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not far off, you wanted to use `nth-child` as opposed to `first-child` (first child is just for the first child).

`li:nth-child(3n+2)` roughly means every 3rd li starting from position 2 and `li:nth-child(3n+3)` means starting at position 3 so on and so forth.

```css
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: green;
}
li:nth-child(3n+4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Not sure why being British is note worthy but I am too ;-)

Comment: Thanks Andrew - just warding off comments about using the UK spelling of `colour`  :-)

Answer (score 5):

You were close. Try:

```
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: green;
}
li:nth-child(3n+4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(3n+4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Transparent</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So near, but so far...!  ;-)  Thank you :-)

Comment: So you're aware, I accepted the answer by Andrew purely for the extra description he added as to how it works.  Still appreciate the quick response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div:not(:nth-child(1)) {
 background-color: orange !important; 
}  

.ele-1 {
 background-color: red; 
}  

.ele-2 {
 background-color: blue;  
}  

.ele-3 {
 background-color: yellow;   
}  

.ele-4 {
 background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div class="ele ele-1"></div>
<div class="ele ele-2"></div>
<div class="ele ele-3"></div>
<div class="ele ele-4"></div>
```

Here what we do is use the `:not` pseudo selector to select everything but the first child, overriding whatever color they had and making it orange, except for the first one. We use that combined with a simple `nth-child(1)` to get everything except the first.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I would suggest that if you're going to answer the question you make sure the snippet works before submitting it

Comment: Sorry for being late on this one, but on my end, the snippet works. For reference, using chrome 50.

Comment: Sorry, but it really doesn't work - I see one red div, followed by three yellow divs (tested in Chrome 51, FF47 and IE11). Absolutely nothing like what I needed.  But thanks for trying

Comment: Whoops, just realized I screwed up, didn't read the entire question, thought you wanted everything but the first. Sorry for wasting your time :(